# ¿Me sale error en el espacio de registrarse? Es PHP

Tags: php

este es el error

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\Pagina\2 Vista\Registrarse.php:1) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Pagina\Index.php on line 20

Estos es lo que tengo:

```
<?php

    require('3 Controlador/Usuario.php');

    if(isset($_POST['Vista_Registrarse']) || isset($_POST['Crear'])){
        Usuario_Común_C::Vista_Registrarse();
        unset($_POST['Vista_Registrarse']);
        unset($_POST['Crear']);
        header('Location: Index.php');
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['Vista_Iniciar_Sesión']) || isset($_POST['Leer'])){
        Usuario_Común_C::Vista_Iniciar_Sesión();
        unset($_POST['Vista_Iniciar_Sesión']);
        unset($_POST['Leer']);
        header('Location: Index.php');
    }
    else{
        Usuario_Común_C::Vista_Iniciar_Sesión();
    }

?>
```

esta es otra clase el archivo se llama Usuario.php

```
class Usuario_Común_C{

    Public function Vista_Iniciar_Sesión(){
        require_once('2 Vista/Iniciar_Sesión.php');
        require_once('2 Vista/Footer.php');
    }

    Public function Vista_Registrarse(){
        require_once('2 Vista/Registrarse.php');
        require_once('2 Vista/Footer.php');
    }
}
```

Y acá esta el archivo Registrarse.php

```html
<form action="Index.php" method="Post" class="Registro_Iniciar_Sesión">

    <h1 class="Cero">Registrarse</h1>
    <input type="text" name="Nombres" class="Uno" Placeholder="Nombres">
    <input type="text" name="Apellidos" class="Dos" Placeholder="Apellidos">
    <input type="text" name="Correo" class="Tres" Placeholder="Correo Electronico">
    <div class="Cuatro">

    </div>
    <input type="text" name="Telefono" class="Cinco" Placeholder="Telefono">
    <input type="password" name="Contraseña" class="Seis" Placeholder="Contraseña">
    <input type="password" name="Verificar_Contraseña" class="Siete" Placeholder="Verificar Contraseña">
    <input type="submit" name="Crear" value="Aceptar" class="Ocho">
    <input type="submit" name="Vista_Iniciar_Sesión" value="Iniciar Sesión" class="Nueve">

</form>
```

y pues el error no hace referencias a mas archivos por lo que no muestro mas de mi código pero si necesitan me avisan, les agradecería mucho si me ayudan.

Comment: Algo en `Registrarse.php` está pintando algo en pantalla (está enviando un HTML, un print, alguna cosa) antes de llegar al `header(Location: xyz)`. Revisa en cuál require o vista pasa eso

Comment: el problema es que creo que por defecto mi código muestra el html de iniciar sesión, y pues si por el método post  se verifica que existe el botón registrarse, lo que va a hacer es rescribir con otro html y para mostrar el formulario de registrarse y lo llevara al index de nuevo pero rescribiendo el nuevo html, entonces sabiendo eso no tengo idea de como arreglarlo ya que lo que quiero es mantener eso la recursividad, que es solo llamar archivos aparte para reescribir: acá todo por si quiere ver: https://github.com/kaslack/Php-problema